# How to get rid of iOS 8 ModelView with round corners

Tags: objective-c, ios8

With iOS8 iPad modal views now have rounded corners (UIModalPresentationFormSheet). Is there a way I can remove this behaviour? I have tried setting the view.layer.cornerRadius to 0 but this doesn’t work (how you would set corners on iOS7). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.superview.layer.cornerRadius = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

From the visible view within a `UINavigationController` opened in a modal:

`self.parentViewController.view.superview.layer.cornerRadius`